# Как пересобрать .lib файл?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lib

Есть у меня .lib файл для старой версии Visual Studio. Как я понял, чтобы использовать его, надо пересобрать этот .lib файл в актуальной версии вижуалки. Как это сделать?

Comment: для начала Вам нужны сорцы (исходный код). Он есть?

Comment: Зависит от того, что именно в нем устарело. Что? Формат .lib архива? Формат .obj файлов, хранящихся в архиве? Или и то, и другое?

Answer (score 0):

Если есть dll, то загружайте её динамически, получите адрес нужной функции и вызывайте ее.